# On iOS and Cocoa Touch, should we assume we should always send "super" the same message?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In iOS and Cocoa Touch, sometimes it seems we can get by without calling super, such as:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // nothing weird if the following is not called:  
    //     [super viewDidAppear: animated]
    // but the docs says we should call it
}
```

and I think with `drawRect`, we usually won't send `super` that same message, unless the `super` is doing some drawing of its own.  Is it true that we should always send `super` the same message just to be safe in Cocoa Touch and iOS, and are there cases, then, not not send `super` the same message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no general rule, it always depends on the class you're subclassing and method you're overriding. NSObject is the root of the class hierarchy in (modern) Objective-C and obviously it doesn't implement most of the methods you see and use, so always calling super wouldn't make sense as a general rule.

You just have to check the documentation for each method separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say this in general. Only one thing is sure: call super if you want the functionality that the method being overridden does, and don't call it if you don't.